# Разница двух дат в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, дата

В ячейке таблицы есть дата в формате дд.мм.рррр Нужно чтобы после того как настоящая дата превысит эту например на 50 дней цвет ячейки изменился

Comment: @Roman19927, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так расчитывается разница дат (в днях):

```
function getDayDelta(
    incomingDate, //новая дата
    todayDate //текущая дата
){
  var incomingDate = new Date(incomingDate[0],incomingDate[1]-1,incomingDate[2]),
      today = new Date(todayDate[0], todayDate[1]-1, todayDate[2]), delta;
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  today.setMilliseconds(0);

  delta = incomingDate - today;

  return Math.round(delta / 1000 / 60 / 60/ 24);
}

getDayDelta( [2014,2,2], [2014,1,2] );
```

Надеюсь сам парсить дату из ячейки таблицы сможешь?

Пример: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcAGG/)

Comment: Чуть проще:

    var cell_date = new Date(2014,0,20); // месяцы 0-11, дни 1-31
    var today = new Date();
    var diffTime = Math.abs( today.getTime() - cell_date.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil( diffTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // в большую сторону
    alert( diffDays + ' дней');

([пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/VVaFS/))

Comment: Это когда даты статичные. А у меня с любыми работает.

Comment: @FlamesoFF, даа, вот это особенно удалось:

> today = new Date(todayDate[0], todayDate[1]-1, todayDate[2])

Comment: @sergiks, ну да.

Comment: @sergiks, если тебе захотелось выежнуться, то надо было так: 
alert( Math.ceil( Math.abs( new Date(2014,0,20).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) + ' дней');

Comment: Тогда уж так : )

    alert(Math.ceil(Math.abs((new Date(2014,0,20)).getTime()-(new Date).getTime())/864e5)+" дней")

Или как функция от "нормальных" месяцев 1-12:

    alert((function(y,m,d){return(Math.ceil(Math.abs((new Date(y,--m,d)).getTime()-(new Date).getTime())/864e5)+" дней")})(2014,1,20));

Comment: @sergiks, это уже не "проще".

    (new Date().getTime()-new Date(2014,0,20).getTime())/864e5;

Comment: @FlamesoFF, "`new Date().getTime()`" вроде работает, но синтакс некорректен: надо всё-таки в скобки заключить: `(new Date())`

Comment: Тогда уж так:

    (+new Date()-+new Date(2014,0,20))/864e5